# Python: Remove a single entry in a list based on the position of the entry

Tags: python, list, variables

Is there an easy way to delete an entry in a list? I would like to only remove the first entry. In every forum that I have looked at, the only way that I can delete one entry is with the `list.remove()` function. This would be perfect, but I can only delete the entry if I know it's name.

```
    list = ['hey', 'hi', 'hello', 'phil', 'zed', 'alpha']
    list.remove(0)
```

This doesn't work because you can only remove an entry based on it's name. I would have to run `list.remove('hey')`. I can't do this in this particular instance.

If you require any additional information, ask.

Comment: Just use `list.pop(0)`

Comment: Are you just removing the first entry? `.pop()` would it for you. Or do you need to remove a random single entry in the list e.g. could be [0] or [3], etc.?

Comment: `list.remove(list.index('hey'))`

Comment: Even if you could only remove an item by its contents, you know its contents: it's `list[0]`. So if you wanted to remove the first item using `remove` it'd be `list.remove(list[0])`. But don't do it that way, use `pop()` or `del`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are methods you can try:

```
>>> my_list = ['hey', 'hi', 'hello', 'phil', 'zed', 'alpha']
>>> del my_list[0]
>>> my_list = ['hey', 'hi', 'hello', 'phil', 'zed', 'alpha']
>>> if 'hey' in my_list:     # you're looking for this one I think
...     del my_list[my_list.index('hey')]
... 
>>> my_list
['hi', 'hello', 'phil', 'zed', 'alpha']
```

You can also use `filter`:

```
 my_list = filter(lambda x: x!='hey', my_list)
```

Using `list comprehension`:

```
my_list = [ x for x in my_list if x!='hey']
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, never call something "list" since it clobbers the built-in type 'list'.  Second of all, here is your answer:

```
>>> my_list = ['hey', 'hi', 'hello', 'phil', 'zed', 'alpha']
>>> del my_list[1]
>>> my_list
['hey', 'hello', 'phil', 'zed', 'alpha']
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists work with **positions**, not **keys** (or names, whatever you want to call them).

If you need *named access* to your data structure consider using a dictionary instead which allows access to its value by using `keys` which map to the `values`.

```
d = {'hey':0, 'hi':0, 'hello':0, 'phil':0, 'zed':0, 'alpha':0}

del d['hey']

print(d)  # d = {'alpha': 0, 'hello': 0, 'hi': 0, 'phil': 0, 'zed': 0}
```

Otherwise you will need to resort to index based deletion by getting the index of the element and calling `del alist[index]`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the poll of answers..how about:

```
>>> my_list = ['hey', 'hi', 'hello', 'phil', 'zed', 'alpha']
>>> my_list=my_list[1:]
>>> my_list
['hi', 'hello', 'phil', 'zed', 'alpha']
```